# Syncing gradle fails with SAXParseException during running Flutter app

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

After updating flutter to version 3.7.12 on my project , i cannot start the app anymore with this error :

```
Warning: Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
.
.
.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':webview_flutter_android:compileDebugAidl'.
> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException (no error message)
```

when i downgrade , everything work as before and when i open the android folder as new project it just instantly throws same error.
tried `flutter clean` , `flutter pub cache clean/repair` , removing whole `.gradle` folder , changing project java versions.
i am running this on Mac with macOS Ventura 13.3.1 on M2 chip.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was due to a corrupted android build tools (it was a version-rc one), after removing that and getting another one the error is gone